# Error parsing text from specific class in beautifulsoup soup

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text from a complicated newssite. Example HTML code:

```
<div class="article-section clearfix">

  <p style="line-height:1em;">
<span class="spTextSmaller">Wenig Zeit? Am Textende gibt's eine Zusammenfassung. </span>
</p>

<p>
<hr noshade="1"/>
</p>
  <p>Das Ende der Welt ...</p>

<p>Brzezinski ... </p>

  <p>blubla</p>

  <p>tututut</p>

  <div class="asset-box spPhotoGallery spPhotoGalleryZitat article-quote-gallery">
    <div class="asset-title">"Ich werde es niemals ausschließen"</div>
        <div class="zitat-box">
                <a href="" class="zitat-box-button"><img src="..." height="48" width="48" alt="Zitate starten" />
                </a><a href="..." title="Zitate starten" class="zitat-box-content">... </a></div>
            <p>Zitate starten: Klicken Sie auf den Pfeil</p>
        </div>

  <p>Blabla ..."</p>

  <p>randomletters </p>
</div>
```

I want to extract all the text between the tags of the class "article-section clearfix so in this example

```
['Das Ende der Welt ... ', 'Brzezinski ... ', 'blubla', 'tututut', 'Blabla ..."', 'randomletters ']
```

It should not include "Zitate starten: Klicken Sie auf den Pfeil" which is the p-tag in the big div class "asset-box spPhotoGallery .." .

Currently I am using

```
textlist=[]
for tag in articlesoup.find_all("p"):
       if(tag.parent["class"]==['article-section', 'clearfix']):      
              textlist.append(tag.get_text() + "\n")
       else: continue
```

This results in

> KeyError: 'class

'
For other pages of the website without the div class="asset-box spPhotoGallery spPhotoGalleryZitat article-quote-gallery" it works fine. Classes like ['article-image-description'] are no problem. I have not found an answer to my problem in the other beautifulsoup related questions here.

Getting all text from the ['article-section', 'clearfix'] class by

```
for tag in articlesoup.find_all("div", class_=['article-section, 'clearfix']): tag. get_text()
```

results in too much unwanted stuff, thats why I have to stick with the above mentioned solution probably. 
Should I use some try method to avoid the error? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: In this specific example, what do you want the `textlist` to have after the execution?

Comment: It should include all the text in the <p> tags so in this example it should look like ['Durch ..r ', "Wir ...", 'Die ...']

Comment: The 'Wir ...' and 'Die ...' are not children of the div with class 'article-section' and 'clearfix'. Why are you checking if the tag has a parent with this classes?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the html example. They are the children, when I print tag.parent["class"] it says so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to use *recursive=False*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for p in soup.find("div",class_="article-section clearfix").find_all("p", recursive=False):
    text = p.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
    if text:
        print(text)
```

*soup.find("div",class_="article-section clearfix").find_all("p", recursive=False)* gets all the p who are children of the *div* then text = *p.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()* finds any text that is under the p tags excluding children of the tags.

You can see running on your sample we get what we want:

```
In [8]: html = """<div class="article-section clearfix">
  <p styfrom bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        html = """<div class="article-section clearfix">
  <p styfrom bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        html = """<div class="article-section clearfix">
  <p style="line-height:1em;">
<span class="spTextSmaller">Wenig Zeit? Am Textende gibt's eine Zusammenfassung. </span>
</p>
<p>
<hr noshade="1"/>
</p>
  <p>Das Ende der Welt ...</p>
<p>Brzezinski ... </p>
  <p>blubla</p>
  <p>tututut</p>
  <div class="asset-box spPhotoGallery spPhotoGalleryZitat article-quote-gallery">
    <div class="asset-title">"Ich werde es niemals ausschließen"</div>
        <div class="zitat-box">
                <a href="" class="zitat-box-button"><img src="..." height="48" width="48" alt="Zitate starten" />
                </a><a href="..." title="Zitate starten" class="zitat-box-content">... </a></div>
            <p>Zitate starten: Klicken Sie auf den Pfeil</p>
        </div>
  <p>Blabla ..."</p>
  <p>randomletters </p>
</div>"""
```

Then:

```
In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [10]: for p in soup.find("div", class_="article-section clearfix").find_all("p", recursive=False):
   ....:         text = p.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
   ....:         if text:
   ....:                 print(text)
   ....:         
Das Ende der Welt ...
Brzezinski ...
blubla
tututut
Blabla ..."
randomletters
```

Why your code errors is that you are recursively looking for p tags and somewhere at least one of the p tags has a parent that has no class which the following demonstrates:

```
In [13]: html = """<div><p>foo</p> <>"""

In [14]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [15]: print(soup.find("p").parent["class"])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c4921fc9e631> in <module>()
----> 1 print(soup.find("p").parent["class"])

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    956         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
    957         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
--> 958         return self.attrs[key]
    959 
    960     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 'class'

In [16]: html = """<div class="bar"><p>foo</p> <>"""

In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [18]: print(soup.find("p").parent["class"])
['bar']
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that suggestion. There is just one problem: if an ahref object is included in the p tag, it is stripped to the part before the link. For example "Die von Obama .. <a href="bla">umfassende Modernisierung des nuklearen Arsenals</a> tatata.</p> " becomes "Die von Obama .. "

Comment: @Tyrion, I don't understand what you mean, you said you wanted text, how does an anchor fit into it? If you want the text in the anchor then you would just print p.text but that would also pull *Wenig Zeit? Am Textende gibt's eine Zusammenfassung.* which you don't want .

Comment: I want the whole sentence, including the part after the link. The "tatata" is stripped from the text. I just dont get the second part of the sentence with your method